# Python GSpread - Loop through rows

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to loop through the rows on a Google sheet using python and gspread. Every time I try to get the values, the list is returned as columns and not rows.

Is there a way to retrieve the rows and loop through them?

Looking here https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-row-or-a-column I am not too sure how many rows there will be. Is there a way to count the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import, Authenticate and Open the Sheet as defined by the [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/) documentation:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account()
worksheet = gc.open("Sheet1").sheet1
```

Then use `.get_all_values()` to iterate through the rows:

```
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
for row in rows:
   # ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been going stir crazy about this. I will accept your answer!

Comment: No Problem! Glad I was able to help @StevenHardy